# Problema con Clases y objetos

Tags: python, poo

Estoy realizando un curso y no comprendo cómo realizar una acción específica. Puntualmente la cuestión de POO del curso, a mi gusto, la ha brindado muy superficialmente y no comprendo.

La empresa lleva un par de semanas funcionando con tu clase `Paquete` definida en la pregunta anterior, sin embargo ahora que ya la probaron deciden hacerle un par de cambios para adaptarse a nuevas necesidades.
(esta clase paquete está previamente definida heredada de otra,

```python
class Paquete(Envio):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor, max_volumen):
        super().__init__(emisor,receptor)
        self.max_volumen = max_volumen
        self.abiertacaja = True

    def agregar_producto(self, peso, volumen):
        self.peso=peso
        self.volumen=volumen
        if self.abiertacaja==False:
            self.abiertacaja==True

    def cerrar(self):
        if self.volumen < self.max_volumen:
            self.abiertacaja=False
        else:
            pass

    def enviar(self):
        if agregar_producto.peso <=30 and self.abiertacaja == False:
            self.enviar()
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

La empresa tiene una clase `Paquete` la cual cumple todas las condiciones de la pregunta anterior.

Para esta parte deberás definir la clase `PaqueteMejorado`, la cual hereda de `Paquete` y tiene los siguientes cambios:

Un `PaqueteMejorado` no se deberá enviar si su emisor y su receptor son la misma persona. Además, una misma instancia de `PaqueteMejorado` solo se podrá enviar una vez; si se intenta enviar una segunda vez, entonces NO se deberá realizar el segundo envio.

NOTA: No es necesario que redefinas la clase `Paquete`, puedes suponer que ya está definida (de manera equivalente a como Envio ya estaba definida para ambas preguntas anteriores)

Entiendo que debería comenzar así:

```python
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor, max_volumen, paqueteM):
        super().__init__ (emisor, receptor,max_volumen)
        self.paqueteM= paqueteM
```

La condición a cumplir respecto a emisor y receptor creo puede ser trabajada con una instancia `if`, pero tengo problemas para la condición de que solo puede ser enviado una vez.

Comment: si los enunciados los han hecho asi es porque no quieren que se entienda

Comment: es posible jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, deben querer que hagas algo así:

```
class PaqueteMejorado(Paquete):
    def __init__(self, emisor, receptor, max_volumen, paqueteM):
        super().__init__ (emisor, receptor,max_volumen)
        self.enviado = False

    ...

    def enviar(self):
        if self.enviado or self.emisor == self.receptor:
            return False
        if super().enviar():
            self.enviado = True
            return True
        return False
```

Básicamente agregas una variable que permita determinar si el paquete se envió o no. Y cómo habla de que no se puede enviar si no cumple tales condiciones haces la verificación en la función `enviar`.

Comment: GRACIAS! Así como lo indicas parece super simple. No se porque me he complicado tanto. Debere repasar POO para entender bien como abordar los problemas

Comment: @Maximiliano no, solo tienes un muy mal tutor

Comment: @Maximiliano acepta la respuesta dando click en el check del costado que solo puedes verlo tú por ser el creador de la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: @Egon puede ser. Yo creo que es típico que los profesores usen muchas palabras como para dar un contexto al problema. En lugar de ir al grano y decir: extiende la clase, llámala así y modifica la función `enviar` para que no envíe el paquete si ya fue enviado o el remitente es igual al destinatario. En un párrafo entra todo. No sé si lo hacen por formalismo o solo tienen ganas de complicarlo.